# Is it possible to access appsettings.json from a Roslyn Analyzer?

Tags: .net, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

The title says it all really. I've tried using `RegisterAdditionalFileAction` in a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` but it doesn't seem to include the `appsettings*.json` file(s).

Is it even possible? I'd like to write an analyser that would check those files for certain content.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need some MSBuild to specify which files must get passed to the compiler up-front; see [this documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Using%20Additional%20Files.md) for details.